# Uber zap logging having custom message encoder

Tags: go, logging, go-zap

I am using below code to dump logs on console and log file using Uber zap logger. How I can have a custom message encoder so that the output format for the message can be as below?

> `{"severity":"DEBUG","message":"Dec 12, 2018  19:52:39 [log.go:77] Sample debug for log file and console"}`

Below is the code which I am using to dump the logs on the console.

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "time"

    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "go.uber.org/zap/zapcore"
    "gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2"
    "path/filepath"
)

var logLevelSeverity = map[zapcore.Level]string{
    zapcore.DebugLevel:  "DEBUG",
    zapcore.InfoLevel:   "INFO",
    zapcore.WarnLevel:   "WARNING",
    zapcore.ErrorLevel:  "ERROR",
    zapcore.DPanicLevel: "CRITICAL",
    zapcore.PanicLevel:  "ALERT",
    zapcore.FatalLevel:  "EMERGENCY",
}

func SyslogTimeEncoder(t time.Time, enc zapcore.PrimitiveArrayEncoder) {
    enc.AppendString(t.Format("Jan 01, 2006  15:04:05"))
}

func CustomEncodeLevel(level zapcore.Level, enc zapcore.PrimitiveArrayEncoder) {
    enc.AppendString(logLevelSeverity[level])
}

func CustomLevelFileEncoder(level zapcore.Level, enc zapcore.PrimitiveArrayEncoder) {
    enc.AppendString("[" + logLevelSeverity[level] + "]")
}
func funcCaller(caller zapcore.EntryCaller, enc zapcore.PrimitiveArrayEncoder) {
    enc.AppendString(filepath.Base(caller.FullPath()))
}

func main() {

    w := zapcore.AddSync(&lumberjack.Logger{
        Filename:   "temp1.log",
        MaxSize:    1024,
        MaxBackups: 20,
        MaxAge:     28,
        Compress:   true,
    })

    //Define config for the console output
    cfgConsole := zapcore.EncoderConfig{
        MessageKey:   "message",
        LevelKey:     "severity",
        EncodeLevel:  CustomEncodeLevel,
        TimeKey:      "time",
        EncodeTime:   SyslogTimeEncoder,
        CallerKey:    "caller",
        EncodeCaller: funcCaller,
    }
    cfgFile := zapcore.EncoderConfig{
        MessageKey:   "message",
        LevelKey:     "severity",
        EncodeLevel:  CustomLevelFileEncoder,
        TimeKey:      "time",
        EncodeTime:   SyslogTimeEncoder,
        CallerKey:    "caller",
        EncodeCaller: funcCaller,
    }

    consoleDebugging := zapcore.Lock(os.Stdout)
    //consoleError := zapcore.Lock(os.Stderr)
    core := zapcore.NewTee(
        zapcore.NewCore(zapcore.NewConsoleEncoder(cfgFile), w, zap.DebugLevel),
        zapcore.NewCore(zapcore.NewJSONEncoder(cfgConsole), consoleDebugging, zap.DebugLevel),
        //zapcore.NewCore(zapcore.NewJSONEncoder(zap.NewProductionEncoderConfig()), consoleError, zap.ErrorLevel),
    )
    //core := zapcore.NewCore(zapcore.NewConsoleEncoder(encConsole), w, zap.DebugLevel)
    wlogger := zap.New(core, zap.AddCaller())
    wlogger.Debug("Sample debug for log file and console")
    wlogger.Warn("An warning message example")
    wlogger.Info("An info level message")
    coreFile := zapcore.NewCore(zapcore.NewConsoleEncoder(cfgFile), w, zap.DebugLevel)
    flogger := zap.New(coreFile, zap.AddCaller())
    flogger.Debug("An exclusive message for file")
    //output
    //{"severity":"DEBUG","time":"Dec 12, 2018  19:52:39","caller":"log.go:77","message":"Sample debug for log file and console"}
}
```

Any thoughts how to achieve the expected output? We have a requirement for putting the message on the console in above format.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, the following configuration worked for me:

```golang
func logInit(d bool, f *os.File) *zap.SugaredLogger {

    pe := zap.NewProductionEncoderConfig()

    fileEncoder := zapcore.NewJSONEncoder(pe)

    pe.EncodeTime = zapcore.ISO8601TimeEncoder
    consoleEncoder := zapcore.NewConsoleEncoder(pe)

    level := zap.InfoLevel
    if d {
        level = zap.DebugLevel
    }

    core := zapcore.NewTee(
        zapcore.NewCore(fileEncoder, zapcore.AddSync(f), level),
        zapcore.NewCore(consoleEncoder, zapcore.AddSync(os.Stdout), level),
    )

    l := zap.New(core)

    return l.Sugar()
}
```